# A button inside one div affects a different div -- In Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with a `button` inside a `div` that affects a different `div`. Here's the basic outline:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <button>THIS BUTTON</button>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>THIS TABLE</table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Intuitively, I would say that adding or removing that `button` should have no effect on the `table` and the `div` containing the `table`.

I want this `table` to be as wide as possible.

And without the `button` it looks like this:

[image: Table should look like this]

But then I added JavaScript code that exports the `table` contents into a CSV file.

Once I added the button to do this action, the `table` becomes narrower:

[image]

Here's is the sample code as a standalone HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        * {
            color: #2b2b2b;
            font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
        }
        button {
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 0rem;
        }
        .container {
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
        }
        .table td, .table th {
            padding: .25em;
        }
        .table {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('ok?');
            if ($('table').length) {
                $('#export_button').show();
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="max-width: 100%">
    <div class="container" id="page_header">
        <div class="float-right">
            <div>
                <button style="margin-top: 0px; display: none"
                        id="export_button" type="button" onclick="">
                    Export to CSV file
                </button>
                <div class="d-inline">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-fluid img-thumbnail back-link" style="max-width:2em; height:auto;"
                         src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Icon_Arrow_Left_256x256.png" alt="go back" id="back-button">
                </div>
                <img class="img-responsive img-fluid img-thumbnail" style="max-width:2em; height:auto;"
                         src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/1328101942_Arrow-Up.png" alt="menu" id="show_menu">

                <div class="d-inline">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-fluid img-thumbnail forward-link" style="max-width:2em; height:auto;"
                         src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Icon_Arrow_Right_256x256.png" alt="go forward" id="forward-button">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-right login-logout" style="background:transparent; border:none; color:transparent;">
                <a href="/login">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h1><div class="container">A very Informative Header</div></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-responsive table-hover sortable">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>This is Column 1</th><th>This is Column 2</th><th>This is Column 3</th><th>This is Column 4</th><th>This is Column 5</th><th>This is Column 6</th><th>This is Column 7</th><th>This is Column 8</th><th>This is Column 9</th><th>This is Column 10</th><th>This is Column 11</th><th>This is Column 12</th><th>This is Column 13</th><th>This is Column 14</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>45629</td><td>746582945 </td><td>8752</td><td>45234</td><td>342</td><td>658472</td><td>764932</td><td>48753 </td><td></td><td>Something very important</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>3.14159265357989</td><td>13</td><td>42</td><td>7abc</td><td></td><td>Here I have some pretty long text that is not important, but it's here anyway, just to make the table bigger</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's entire sample file in my question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I copied your code into JS snippet. The button doesn't seem to cause any problems.
Quick update: it behaves differently on full screen.
A quick workaround is to add width: 100% to your table's container.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        * {
            color: #2b2b2b;
            font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
        }
        button {
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 0rem;
        }
        .container {
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
        }
        .table td, .table th {
            padding: .25em;
        }
        .table {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            if ($('table').length) {
                $('#export_button').show();
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="max-width: 100%">
    <div class="container" id="page_header">
        <div class="float-right">
            <div>
                <button style="margin-top: 0px; display: none"
                        id="export_button" type="button" onclick="">
                    Export to CSV file
                </button>
                <div class="d-inline">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-fluid img-thumbnail back-link" style="max-width:2em; height:auto;"
                         src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Icon_Arrow_Left_256x256.png" alt="go back" id="back-button">
                </div>
                <img class="img-responsive img-fluid img-thumbnail" style="max-width:2em; height:auto;"
                         src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/1328101942_Arrow-Up.png" alt="menu" id="show_menu">

                <div class="d-inline">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-fluid img-thumbnail forward-link" style="max-width:2em; height:auto;"
                         src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Icon_Arrow_Right_256x256.png" alt="go forward" id="forward-button">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-right login-logout" style="background:transparent; border:none; color:transparent;">
                <a href="/login">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h1><div class="container">A very Informative Header</div></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-responsive table-hover sortable">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>This is Column 1</th><th>This is Column 2</th><th>This is Column 3</th><th>This is Column 4</th><th>This is Column 5</th><th>This is Column 6</th><th>This is Column 7</th><th>This is Column 8</th><th>This is Column 9</th><th>This is Column 10</th><th>This is Column 11</th><th>This is Column 12</th><th>This is Column 13</th><th>This is Column 14</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>45629</td><td>746582945 </td><td>8752</td><td>45234</td><td>342</td><td>658472</td><td>764932</td><td>48753 </td><td></td><td>Something very important</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>3.14159265357989</td><td>13</td><td>42</td><td>7abc</td><td></td><td>Here I have some pretty long text that is not important, but it's here anyway, just to make the table bigger</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, this doesn't help. Still same problem

Comment: @Marjeta I tried it with both chrome and Microsoft Edge ... and it seems to work fine.
Added an print screen to the post.